# Can not locate XPath on Android

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium

Using `Appium`, `UIAutomatoViewer` and Android 5.1

Can you help me please to locate XPath of element. I Need to get text from DVR Boxes (Living Room, *DVR 1* in this example). I was trying different combinations, but still no luck.

I can not use `resource-id` because for `RelativeLayout[0]` and `RelativeLayout[1]` they the same. And I can not search page using text as well, because text is dynamic (DVR boxes will change). I think only solution is XPath

The following is what I did:

1. ```
   AndroidElement d = (AndroidElement)
   driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.TextView[0]");
   ```
2. ```
   AndroidElement d = (AndroidElement)
   driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='0']");
   System.out.println(d.getText());
   ```
3. ```
   AndroidElement d = (AndroidElement) 
   driver.findElementByXPath("//RelativeLayout[0]/TextView[0]");
   ```

But not of my solutions work so far

[image]

Comment: try using the XPath as displayed in the `appium inspector` for the element in the properties section

Comment: Thank you very much.I was using UIAtomatorviewer and did not know that in Appium inspector you can see Full Xpath. UIAtomatorviewer does not have this option so far

Answer (score 0):

> I can not use "resource-id" because for RelativeLayout[0] and
>   RelativeLayout1 they the same

You can still use `resource-ids` creating a `List<WebElement>` and accessing elements using index. In your case something like this :

```
List<WebElement> dvrList = driver.findElementsById("<id of the list element"); //creates a list of elements with same id
String text = dvrList.get(1).getText(); //this gives you text of 2nd element on list (base index 0)
```

> I think only solution is XPath

Unless the Xpath is correct your way of accessing the element seems alright

```
WebElement dvrItem = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ListView[0]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.TextView[0]");
String text = dvrItem.getText();
```

**Edit :-**

```
Correct XPath = //android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.R‌​elativeLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]
```

Comment: Found correct Xpath:      WebElement drv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]"));
        drv.getText();

Comment: hope appium inspector helps :)